# Javascript toggle checkbox 2 class

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have this html code, 
3 checkboxes, the *All* checkbox is to control 1 & 2 checkbox
If I click *All* checkbox, only checkbox with *info[]* name changed. What I need is if I change *All* checkbox, the 1 & 2 checkbox will toggle checked.

```
All: <input type="checkbox" onchange="togglecheckboxesAll(this,'info[]')"> | 

1 <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
2 <input type="checkbox" name="info[]" class="check2"/>
```

And here is the javascript code.

PS :

The selector of checkbox 1 is *class="check"*

The selector of checkbox 2 is *name="info[]"*

```
function togglecheckboxesAll(master,group){
    var cbarray = document.getElementsByName(group);
    var cbarray2 = document.getElementsByName('check');
    for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){
        cbarray[i].checked = master.checked; 
    }

    for(var a = 0; a < cbarray2.length; a++){
        cbarray2[a].checked = master.checked;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry, I don't know much about javascript.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, 
I got the answer, I'm wrong in *getElementsByName* and *getElementsByClassName* :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the classname for the group

```
 all <input type="checkbox" onChange="togglecheckboxesAll(this,'clickgroup')" />

1 <input type="checkbox" class="check clickGroup" />
2 <input type="checkbox" class="check2 clickGroup" />

function togglecheckboxesAll(master, group){
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + matchClass + ' ')
                > -1) {
            elems[i].checked= master.checked;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the code and add double quote(") on line 1 after checkbox?

Comment: Great job @Snowburnt :-D